# Is there a way to speed up create-react-app npm test?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

When I run the command `npm test`, it takes ~10 seconds to load, then it will only run any test files that have had changes. In my case, it's usually one file. The time ends up being 20+ seconds for one file, but the individual tests take 30ms. What is slowing everything else down and how can I speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Create-react-app is always slow because it consists of almost 200mb of content! There are literally thousands of individual packages that are verified before running. Probably nothing that can be done about this apart from Ejecting or using a different tool.